# Need message box or alert to display session time out warning in infopath

Tags: infopath

I've an infopath form, need to display a message box to users alerting them about session time out, any work arounds?

I know a method of using infopath form webpart in a custom page and insert javascript in that to display alert on session time out, but that wouldnt work in my case as the form is not submitted in one instance as user needs to open the form multiple times before it is fully submitted.
So the code needs to be in the template.

Thanks
Vish

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2010, you can modify the Session Timeout within Central Administration:

1. On the Quick Launch of the Central Administration Web site, click General Application Settings.
2. On the General Application Settings page, in the InfoPath Forms Services section, click Configure InfoPath Form Services.
3. In the User Sessions section, configure the following parameters:
4. In the Active sessions should be terminated after box, type the maximum session duration in minutes.Form-filling sessions that are longer than this limit are ended, generate an error message, and lose all form data that was entered during the session. The default value is 1,440 minutes.
5. Click OK to save the settings.

Comment: Hi James thanks for the response, its not about changing the time out settings, its about letting the user know that the form will be timed out(say by using alert or message box) we are not allowed to modify the settings in central admin and more over i am working on SharePoint 2013.